# Inventory project. How to total the value of same name objects in queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have multiple breweries with multiple beers. Some are the same. I need to give a company itemized total. This code iterates over the queryset, finds duplicate names, totals the quantity and then adds it to a dictionary. If no duplicate it goes straight to the dictionary. I'm new to Python and Django so the code is elementary and clunky. Please advise me on more elegant and concise methods to solve this problem. Thanks!

```
def index_inventory(request):
    keg_totals = {}
    keg_data = Kegs.objects.all()
    counter = 0
    for keg in keg_data:
        counter2 = counter + 1
        while counter2 <= (len(keg_data)) -1:
            if (keg_data[counter].beer) == (keg_data[counter2].beer):
                (keg_data[counter2].quantity) =(keg_data[counter2].quantity)+ 
                  (keg_data[counter].quantity)   
                counter2 += 1
            else:
                keg_totals[keg.beer] = keg.quantity     
            counter2 += 1      
        counter += 1

    context = {
        'keg_totals' : keg_totals,
    }
    return render(request, 'inventory/index_inventory.html', context)
```

<QuerySet [<Kegs: 33rd State 7.75 -5>, <Kegs: 33rd State 7.75 -10>, <Kegs: Fresh Harvest 15 -35>, <Kegs: Fresh Harvest 15 -30>, <Kegs: Hammerhead 15 -25>, <Kegs: Hammerhead 15 -15>, <Kegs: Hammerhead 15 -40>, <Kegs: Purple Haze 15 -20>, <Kegs: Purple Haze 15 -25>, <Kegs: Purple Haze 7.75 -5>, <Kegs: Sunflower 15 -30>, <Kegs: Sunflower 15 -10>, <Kegs: Terminator Stout 15 -20>, <Kegs: Terminator Stout 5 -5>, <Kegs: xxx -0>]>

Name and keg size with quantity.

Comment: Could you share an example of what `keg_data` might look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a collection of kegs:

```
class Keg:

    def __init__(self, beer, quantity):
        self.beer = beer
        self.quantity = quantity


kegs = [
    Keg("Ale", 10),
    Keg("Lager", 25),
    Keg("Ale", 2),
    Keg("Stout", 4),
    Keg("Lager", 10)
]
```

You could do:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

key = attrgetter("beer")

keg_totals = { beer: sum(keg.quantity for keg in group) for beer, group in groupby(sorted(kegs, key=key), key=key)}
print(keg_totals)
```

Output:

```
{'Ale': 12, 'Lager': 35, 'Stout': 4}
```

---

Explanation:

First we create a sorted version of the collection of kegs via `sorted(kegs, key=attrgetter("beer"))`. We are sorting based on `key`, which in this case means we're sorting based on lexicographical ordering of each keg's `beer` property (we're sorting alphabetically based on `beer` name):

```
[
    Keg("Ale", 10),
    Keg("Ale", 2),
    Keg("Lager", 25),
    Keg("Lager", 10),
    Keg("Stout", 4)
]
```

Then, we create a list of groups based on kegs in this sorted collection that are adjacent to each other and share the same `beer` name via `groupby`:

```
[
    [ Keg("Ale", 10), Keg("Ale", 2)],
    [ Keg("Lager", 25), Keg("Lager", 10)],
    [ Keg("Stout", 4)]
]
```

In this example, we have three groups.

Then, using a dictionary-comprehension, we generate a dictionary: For each group in our list of groups, set the current key to be the `beer` name that's associated with the current group, and set the current value to the sum of all quantities of all kegs in the current group.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your clear, quick and concise solution! I will investigate how I can integrate this into my project.